# Class loading issue with JBOSS 6.3.0

Tags: java, spring, jboss, web-deployment, jboss-eap-6

I'm running the following class loading issue with JBOSS.

My JBOSS's module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.example">
  <resources>
        ...
        <resource-root path="spring-amqp-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
        ...
  </resources>  
</module>
```

When `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper:getClassIdType(String classId)` is called

`MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name...` is thrown by

```
ClassUtils.forName(classId, getClass()
          .getClassLoader())
```

Debugging `getClass().getClassLoader()` returns `ModuleClassLoader for Module "com.example:main".`

So it seems the issue is the class I'm deserializing is not in module `com.example` (defined in `module.xml`) so it throws that exception

My`jboss-deployment-structure.xml` has `com.example` as a dependency:

```
 <dependencies>
            <module name="com.example">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF**"/>
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
```

I can fix this problem if I remove `spring-amqp-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar` from `module.xml` and add `spring-amqp` to my `build.gradle`. Problem is `module.xml` is shared across my org and I can't change that.

So how can I fix this? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

A stacktrace (and some more code) to reproduce would be nice. I am not familiar with amqp.

In https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java at line 56, ClassUtils.forName(classId, getClass().getClassLoader()) gets called, but can't find the class.

In JBoss, module classloaders are seperated from application classloaders. In your application, you can access all classes from the module, but the module can't access your WAR or JAR classes. 
So, this is exception is thrown, because your module, tries to load a class from your application, which is not visible in the module classloader. But if you add the amqp-jar to your application, it works, because they share the same classloader.

If you want/need amqp in a module, you need to create a module with your application common-classes and add it to your module as a dependency. But also note, you can't add the common.jar to the application.jar anymore to avoid classCastExceptions. 
I don't know, how amqp is used, but probably, you need to create multiple modules to use it with different common.jars.

For more information about jboss classloading, i can refer you to: 
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/discover-jboss-as-7-modularity
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html

Comment: Your reply helped me understand a lot more but I’m still a bit lost. The `module.xml` in JBOSS is shared so I cannot modify it. So is there a way to tell JBOSS `jboss-deployment-structure` to use my application’s module to load amqp instead of the common (`com.example`) module?

Comment: I am pretty sure, you have no chance to fix that issue without modifying module.xml. Why do you need to use a module, maybe you can ask your colleges or system architect, if they ever made a proof of concept. Or you add the jar, without adding the module by adding     <resource-root path="../../../../../../../../../modules/com/example/spring-amqp-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar" /> in jboss-deployment-structure.xml, which i wouldn't recommend